# How to manipulate the Global Variable in C

Tags: c, function, global-variables

I have multiple `void functions` that relies on the each individual output of the functions since there are multiple variables (that are the same throughout the code), where each functions' output will be "stored" to them and be passed to another.

So, I decided to make those variables into global variables by making them `static ....` right after all the necessary `#include...` codes.

I was able to utilize all functions (14 functions in total,all `void`) by only calling four of them (Each functions, after processing its own function, passes the result into another function and after series of passing, only four of them are needed to be called in `int main()`)

Now, I created another `void function` that requires the global variables as its parameter since that `void function` relies on the data that all the other functions "copied and put" into the global variables declared earlier. (Which I found is not working, since I heard that storing data into global variables is not possible.)

Can anyone teach me if there is any other way to create series of functions which requires output of each individual functions?

I checked if the variables were stored properly, so I tried using `printf` method right after the #3 process. I found out nothing gets printed when I expected a value from the `struct data` to be printed.

---

Ex:

```
typedef struct database{
//... variables
}data;

typedef struct itembase{
//... variables
}item;

static data user1;
static data user2;
static data *pointer[10000];
static item *pointer2[10000];
static item current[10000]; //Shares same value of the bracket with *pointer2
static data sectionA[1][10000];
static data sub_section[3][10000];
static int datacounter = 0; //..will be put inside the bracket of *pointer
static int itemcounter = 0; //..will be put inside the bracket of *pointer2 
static int typenum = 0; ..will be put inside the first bracket of all the sections and subsections
static int section_count = 0; //..will be put inside the second bracket of all sections
static int sub_section_count[3] = {0}; //..will be put inside the second bracket of all sub_sections. The [3] will be the value of the typenum.

void load_data() // Accepts User's input and store them into struct data's variable using singly-linked list
{
//.... All data will be stored to *pointer[datacounter]
binarycheck(pointer[datacounter]->encoding,*pointer,datacounter);
//.... The `typedef struct` of data contains 12 variables. After storing 12 variables, datacounter will be ++ and the program will still continue to accept input from the user
}

void load_item()
{
//.... All item will be stored to *pointer2[itemcounter]
memcpy(&current[itemcounter],pointer2[itemcounter],sizeof(item)); 
}

void binarycheck(data encoding,data *pointer,int datacounter)
{
if ((encoding&128)==128){
typenum = 3; 
memcpy(&sectionA[typenum][section_count],pointer,sizeof(data)); 
sub_sectionA[typenum][sub_section_count[typenum]] = sectionA[typenum[section_count]; 
section_count++;
sub_section_count++;
}
}

void askitem(data user)
{
// Tried putting `printf(" %s User1 Data#1",user1.firstdata);` and it works perfectly fine.
// Ask for user's selection on item
// If the item is found, then the content of that item will modify the data of the variable of `user`
}

void askinput(data user) 
{ 
int whattype = 0;
int whatsub = 0;

  printf("What type do you want?: \n);
  scanf("%d",&whattype);
  if (whattype == 1)
  {typenum = 1;}
  printf("What Sub type do you want?: \n);
  scanf("%d",&whatsub);
  if (whatsub == 1)
  { user = sub_sectionA[typenum][sub_section_count[typenum]];}
  askitem(user);
} 

void final_print(data user, data user2)
{
printf("%d\n",user.Adata);
printf("%d\n",user2.Adata);
}

int main()
{
load_data();
load_item();
askinput(user1);
//Tried putting `printf(" %s User1 Data#1",user1.firstdata);` but nothing shows.
askinput(user2);
//Nothing shows
final_print(user1,user2); //Nothing shows
}
```

Comment: Your variable are in different file or same main file?

Comment: @sujin I am just using Single Main File

Comment: can you give the full sample code.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You are calling function from within functions and finally the first function finally makes the final changes in your global variables.

Comment: Not able to find the real problem from you question.. static global variable has file scope so it will give the last updated value.

Comment: You've spent an age writing an entire program, and are now trying to debug the huge morass. You cannot see the wood for the trees. Write a 10 line SSCCE to demonstrate your problem.

Comment: Please don't ask us to e-mail you (I guess your comment got deleted because we don't do e-mail support here). The next step is for you to explain your problem by removing as much code as possible and giving a complete, short program that demonstrates whatever it is you do not understand. Then we will explain and you will learn.

Comment: No. Your code does nothing. You are asking why a program that never calls anything and consists entirely of empty functions and comments does nothing. There's also way too much of it. Strip it down to the bare minimum, but no so far that the unexpected behaviour disappears. You might need 10 variables, we surely only need one or two. You should be able to do it in a complete program in say 20 lines. Do you know what an SSCCE is? And if not why not? Hint: search the web when you don't know stuff.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan followed what I can from the SSCCE. Storing data and item is just singly-linked list method. Adding it will just make my code messier (and it is not the problem I am facing).

Comment: Well, I think I can see the problem, but the code is still way to long. The first S in SSCCE stands for short. That is critical. That's why it's the first word in the acronym. The reason the question has been painful is because you weren't able to make a good SSCCE. If you take anything away from this, please let it be that lesson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this function:

```
void askinput(data user)
```

Here you pass `user` by value to the function. When you pass by value, the function receives a copy of the variable. Changes that you make inside the body of that function only affect the copy. They are not visible to the caller's variable.

Instead you need to pass a reference. In C that means passing a pointer to a variable:

```
void askinput(data *user)
```

Inside the body of the function you need to de-reference the pointer to access members. So you use `->` rather than `.` to refer to members.

And when you call the function you need to pass a pointer to the variable. So the call becomes:

```
askinput(&user1);
```

Frankly I do not understand why you are using global variables here at all. It's generally preferable to pass parameters otherwise you do find yourself struggling to keep track of which different version of the variable you are meant to be working on.

Finally, you have written your entire program and trying to debug this specific problem in the context of the entire program is confusing you. You really should have cut this down to a 10 or 20 line simple reproduction. Being able to do that in the future will make life much easier for you.

Comment: I don't understand that comment. All I've done is explain why your modifications to variables passed by value, are not seen in the variable that the caller passes. As for how to write your program, I wouldn't do it the way you are doing it.

Comment: Okay, I have rephrased my question: What does `&` exactly do in calling? What's its difference when without it?

Comment: @BeginnerC That's the operator that takes the address of an object. So, `user` is a struct, and `&user` is the address of that struct.

Comment: Sorry, no. I don't know what your code is meant to be doing. Please don't ask me to help you debug the rest of it.